# Gap in toolbar, Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, toolbar

How can I get rid of this gap within the toolbar, next to the refresh button? As you can see it is only visible once run within the iPad simulator :( I wish for it to look exactly as the storyboard displays it, with the refresh button pushed to the end of the toolbar. I am new to Xcode so any help is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how exactly you would like the segmented control and the refresh button displayed, you should use the `Fixed Space Bar Button Item` and `Flexible Space Bar Button Item` element in the Storyboard.
If you want the segmented control in the center and the refresh control on the right, you should do the following:

```
<-->SegmentedControl<-->RefreshBarButtonItem
```

where <--> means `Flexible Space`

Example with Storyboard on the left and the result in the simulator on the right:
[image: UIToolbar arrangement example]

Comment: Hi, I did this but still the space on the right of the toolbar persists :( Any idea why? Thanks for your suggestion regardless :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? If you have arranged the toolbar items as I showed inside the toolbar, it should layout just right.